How to determine the PDF of $\{a+bx\}$, the fractional part of a linear function?
Consider a linear function $y=f(x)=a+bx$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers. Specifically, $a \in [0,1]$, and $b >0$.  $x$ belongs to positive integers, that is, $x=1,2,…,+\infty$. I aim to determine the probability density function (PDF) or probability mass function (PMF) of $\{y\}$ given $N$ $x$s. More specifically, $x$ takes values sequentially from $1$ to $N$, i.e., $x=1,2,…, N$. The goal is to determine the distribution of remainders of $y$ for these $N$ values. Actually, $N$ is more likely to be a random variable rather than $x$. But when solving this problem, I hope to find an analytical expression of the PDF or PMF for $\{y\}$ as $N$ approaches $+\infty$.
For example:
If $a=0.5$, $b=2.5$, $x$ takes values $sequentially$ from $1$ to $N$. That is, I will substitute $x=1$ into $f(x)$, we have $y_1=f(1)=3$.
Next, I will substitute $x=2$ into $f(x)$, we have $y_2=f(2)=5.5$. Then, I will substitute $x=3$ into $f(x)$, we have $y_3=f(3)=8$. Finally, we can have a sequence of $Y=3,5.5,8,10.5,13,……$. The PMF can be written as when N approaches $+\infty$
$$\begin{cases} 
P(\{y\}=0) &= 1/2 \\
P(\{y\}=0.5) &= 1/2
\end{cases}$$
To tackle this problem, I represent $a$ and $b$ as irreducible fractions:
$$a=\frac{a_m}{a_n}$$ and $$b=\frac{b_m}{b_n},$$ where $a_m$, $a_n$, $b_m$, and $b_n$ are all of positive integers. Therefore, we have $$a+bx= \frac{a_m b_n + x a_n b_m}{a_n b_n}.$$ It can be found that the fractional part of $y$ corresponds to :
$$\{a+bx\} = \frac{k}{a_n b_n},$$ where $k=0,1,2,…,a_nb_n-1$. However, I cannot determine the probabilities associated with each $\frac{k}{a_n b_n}$. Any guidance on how to derive the PDF or PMF for $\{a + bx\}$ would be greatly appreciated!

The probabilities depend on the distribution of the random variable $x$. PS: It is good practice to use uppercase letters for random quantities and lowercase letters for nonrandom quantities.

@framago Thank you for pointing out the issue, which made me realize a key detail was unclear. Let me rephrase the question for better clarity: $x$ takes values sequentially from 1 to $N$ ($x = 1, 2, \dots, N$), but $x$ is not a random variable. The goal is to determine the distribution of remainders for these $N$ values. Actually, $N$ is more likely to be a random variable rather than x. But when solving this problem, I hope to find the analytical expression of the PDF or PMF of ${y}$ given a large $N$.

The PDF is something related to continuous random variables, while the PMF is related to discrete random variables. If $x$ is nonrandom, then so is $y$. Thus it doesn't make sense to talk about the PDF or the PMF of $y$.

If $N\in d\mathbb N$ and $X$ takes the values $1,2,3,\dots,N$ with the same probability, then $X$ is uniformly distributed over $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed over the set $S_{a,b}$.

If $N\notin d\mathbb N$ and $X$ takes the values $1,2,3,\dots,N$ with the same probability, then $X$ is "almost uniformly distributed" over $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$, because some equivalence classes of $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$ will have $[N/d]$ representatives among the values $1,2,3,\dots,N$, while the remaining equivalence classes will have $[N/d]+1$ representatives among the values $1,2,3,\dots,N$. Thus, $X$ has almost the same probability to belong to our $d$ equivalence classes. Consequently, $Y$ will also be "almost uniformly distributed" over the set $S_{a,b}$.

I can formalize the result in the "almost" case if you are interested.

@framago Thank you very much for your kind reply.  My way of describing it might have made you overthink. Simply put, what I want to do is substitute the values of $x$ into $f(x)$ in sequence, get a series of $y$, and then analyze the distribution of the remainders of $y$. In other words, I want to find the distribution of the remainders of all results of $f(x)$. I’ve added an example to the question, hoping it will help you understand.

You are welcome, ZeroHero. Always glad to help! In your direct computation you consider the odds coming from a sample of the values of $x$ in which every element appears the same number of times (once, but you could choose twice too, doesn't matter). You are "emulating" the uniform distribution.  You are exactly asking for the PMF of $Y$ when $X$ is uniformly distributed over the set ${1,2,\dots,N}$. I will edit my answer to show that the odds are equal to the values of the PMF of $Y$ in the case in which $X$ is uniformly distributed over the set {1,2,\dots,N}$.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\fp}{\mathrm{frac}}\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over the set $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, that is
$$\P(X=k)=\frac1N,$$
for all $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. Let $a,b$ be two positive rational numbers and define the random variable
$$Y:=\fp(a+bX),$$
where $\fp(\cdot)$ is the fractional part. Since $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers, so are $\fp(a)$ and $\fp(b)$. Thus, both of them are represented by an irreducible fraction, i.e
\begin{align}
\fp(a)=\frac{n_a}{d_a},&&\fp(b)=\frac{n_b}{d_b},
\end{align}
for some $n_a,d_a,n_b,d_b\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\gcd(n_a,d_a)=\gcd(n_b,d_b)=1.$$
Since $\fp(\cdot)$ is periodic with period $1$, we have
\begin{align}
Y&=\fp(a+bX)
\\&=\fp\Bigl([a]+\fp(a)+([b]+\fp(b))X\Bigr)
\\&=\fp\Bigl([a]+\fp(a)+[b]X+\fp(b)X\Bigr)
\\&=\fp\Bigl(\fp(a)+\fp(b)X\Bigr)
\\&=\fp\left(\frac{n_ad_b+n_bd_aX}{d}\right),
\end{align}
where $d:=d_ad_b$. Pick $k\in\{0,1,\dots, d-1\}$. The above identity implies that
\begin{align}
Y=\frac{k}{d}\iff n_ad_b+n_bd_aX \equiv k\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d).
\end{align}
We need to solve a linear congruence. Since $\gcd(n_bd_a,d)=d_a\gcd(n_b,d_b)=d_a$, then our congruence has solutions iff $d_a\mid k-n_ad_b$, that is iff $k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)$. In this case, there are exactly $d_a$ solutions $(\mathrm{mod}\,d)$. Formally, if $k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)$, then there exists $x_k\in\{0,1,\dots,d_b-1\}$ such that
$$Y=\frac{k}{d}\iff X\in \bigsqcup_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\Bigl(x_k+id_b+d\mathbb N\Bigr).$$
If $N\in d\mathbb N$, then the probability that $X$ fall inside one of the sets $h+d\mathbb N$ is the same, because all of them have the same number of elements among the values $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. Thus, we have
$$\P\bigl(X\in h+d\mathbb N\bigr)=\frac{1}{d},$$
for all $h\in\{1,\dots, d\}$.
Finally, the PMF of $Y$ is
\begin{align}
\P\left(Y=\frac{k}{d}\right)&=\P\left(\fp\left(\frac{n_ad_b+n_bd_aX}{d}\right)=\frac{k}{d}\right)
\\&=\P\Bigl(n_ad_b+n_bd_aX \equiv k\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d)\Bigr)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\P\left(X\in \bigsqcup_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\Bigl(x_k+id_b+d\mathbb N\Bigr)\right)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\sum_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\P\Bigl(X\in x_k+id_b+d\mathbb N\Bigr)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\sum_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\frac1d
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\frac{d_a}{d}
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\frac{1}{d_b}
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\in n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z\Bigr\}\frac{1}{d_b}
\\&=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{d_b},&\text{if $k\in n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z$,}\\
0,&\text{if $k\notin n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z$,}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
for all $k\in\{0,1,\dots,d-1\}$.
In conclusion, if $N\in d\mathbb N$, then $Y$ is uniformly distributed over the set
\begin{align}S_{a,b} &= \left\{\frac{k}{d}:k\in(n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z)\cap[0,d)\right\}
\\&= \left(\fp(a)+\frac{1}{d_b}\mathbb Z\right)\cap[0,1),
\end{align}
which contains exactly $d_b$ elements.
What happens in the general case in which $N$ is not assumed to be a multiple of $d$?
Write $N=nd+r$, with $r\in\{0,1,\dots,d-1\}$. Note that
\begin{align}
\Bigl\lvert\bigl(h+d\mathbb N\bigr)\cap\bigl\{1,2,\dots,N\bigr\}\Bigr\rvert=
\begin{cases}
n+1,&\text{if $h\in\{1,\dots,r\}$},\\
n,&\text{if $h\in\{r+1,r+2,\dots,d\}$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Hence, the probability that $X$ fall inside one of the sets $h+d\mathbb N$ is not the same, because does not have the same number of elements among the values $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. But for large $N$, these probabilities are almost equal. In fact
\begin{align}\P\bigl(X\in h+d\mathbb N\bigr)&=\frac{\Bigl\lvert\bigl(h+d\mathbb N\bigr)\cap\bigl\{1,2,\dots,N\bigr\}\Bigr\rvert}{N}\\&=\begin{cases}\frac{n}{N}+\frac1N,&\text{if $h\in\{1,\dots,r\}$},\\
\frac{n}{N},&\text{if $h\in\{r+1,r+2,\dots,d\}$},
\end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{d}-\frac{r/d}{N}+\frac1N,&\text{if $h\in\{1,\dots,r\}$},\\
\frac{1}{d}-\frac{r/d}{N},&\text{if $h\in\{r+1,r+2,\dots,d\}$}.
\end{cases}
\\&=\frac{1}{d}+\mathcal O\left(N^{-1}\right),
\end{align}
for all $h\in\{1,\dots, d\}$. Note that if $r=0$ then the probabilities are all equal, in fact $$N\in d\mathbb N\iff r=0.$$
Finally, the PMF of $Y$ is
\begin{align}
\P\left(Y=\frac{k}{d}\right)&=\P\left(\fp\left(\frac{n_ad_b+n_bd_aX}{d}\right)=\frac{k}{d}\right)
\\&=\P\Bigl(n_ad_b+n_bd_aX \equiv k\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d)\Bigr)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\P\left(X\in \bigsqcup_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\Bigl(x_k+id_b+d\mathbb N\Bigr)\right)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\sum_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\P\Bigl(X\in x_k+id_b+d\mathbb N\Bigr)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\sum_{i=0}^{d_a-1}\left(\frac{1}{d}+\mathcal O\left(N^{-1}\right)\right)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\left(\frac{d_a}{d}+\mathcal O\left(N^{-1}\right)\right)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\equiv n_ad_b\:(\mathrm{mod}\,d_a)\Bigr\}\left(\frac{1}{d_b}+\mathcal O\left(N^{-1}\right)\right)
\\&=\mathcal I\Bigl\{k\in n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z\Bigr\}\left(\frac{1}{d_b}+\mathcal O\left(N^{-1}\right)\right)
\\&=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{d_b}+\mathcal O\left(N^{-1}\right),&\text{if $k\in n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z$,}\\
0,&\text{if $k\notin n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z$,}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
for all $k\in\{0,1,\dots,d-1\}$.
In conclusion, if $N$ is large, then $Y$ is "almost" uniformly distributed over the set
\begin{align}S_{a,b} &= \left\{\frac{k}{d}:k\in(n_ad_b+d_a\mathbb Z)\cap[0,d)\right\}
\\&= \left(\fp(a)+\frac{1}{d_b}\mathbb Z\right)\cap[0,1),
\end{align}
which contains exactly $d_b$ elements.
